# Flask and SQLAlchemy sort in display without new query?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm displaying the results from an SQLAlchemy (Flask-SQLAlchemy) query on a particular view.  However the sorting/order is only set by what I originally passed into the query ( **order_by(desc(SelectedTable.date_changed))** ).  I'm trying to now add functionality that each column that is displayed can be selected to order the presentation.

Is there a way to alter the way a returned query object is sorted once it's returned to create this behavior?  Or will I need to build custom queries for each possible column that could be sorted by and ascending/descending?

Is there a recipe for implementing something like this?  I've tried google, here, the Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy, and SQLAlchemy docs for something along these lines but haven't seen anything that touches on the subject and beginning to think that I'm going to need to use custom queries or without new queries try some JavaScript in the Jinja Template to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: [`order_by`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.order_by) also return a `Query` object instead of the actual result. You can construct different `Query` object base on different `order_by` criterion. But that can't avoid execute sql each time.

Comment: You could look at a project like https://datatables.net